# Firefox OS simulator doesn't detect my device on winXP

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, mobile-phone, simulator

I have a ZTE Open device with Firefox OS.

I followed [this guide](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/08/pushing-a-firefox-os-web-app-to-zte-open-phone/) to push apps to it, but the Firefox OS Simulator doesn't detect it on Windows XP.

If I run `adb devices` it lists `roamer2 device`.

I tried it on Kubuntu (same computer) and Windows Vista (different computer), and it does work.

How can I make it work on Windows XP?

**Versions**:

- Mobile OS: Firefox OS 1.1 (OPEN_FFOS_V1.1.0B01_TME)
- PC OS: Windows XP SP3
- Firefox browser: 25.0.1
- Firefox OS Simulator: 4.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem was that Windows XP Home Edition doesn't have `tasklist.exe`.

And [this thread from answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-performance/how-and-where-do-i-download-and-run-missing/4f11c462-ca6a-4472-8713-b91c107441a5) gives the solution:

> Windows XP Home doesn't include the Tasklist.exe utility, I can't
>   figure out why Microsoft excluded this utility from the Home Edition
>   but you can download a copy of it here: 
>   http://www.computerhope.com/download/winxp.htm  Put the utility in
>   your `Windows\System32` folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want anything extra in your `system32` folder, here is an alternative solution.

In `[FF Profile]\extensions\r2d2b2g@mozilla.org\resources\r2d2b2g\lib\adb.js`,
replace `_isAdbRunning` function (line 235) with the following one:

```
  _isAdbRunning: function() {
    let deferred = Promise.defer();

    let ps, args;
    let platform = Services.appinfo.OS;
    if (platform === "WINNT") {
      ps = "C:\\windows\\system32\\tasklist.exe";
      args = [];
    } else {
      args = ["aux"];
      let psCommand = "ps";

      let paths = env.PATH.split(':');
      let len = paths.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        let fullyQualified = file.join(paths[i], psCommand);
        if (file.exists(fullyQualified)) {
          ps = fullyQualified;
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    if (ps) try {

      let buffer = [];

      subprocess.call({
        command: ps,
        arguments: args,
        stdout: function(data) {
          buffer.push(data);
        },
        done: function() {
          let lines = buffer.join('').split('\n');
          let regex = (platform === "WINNT") ? psRegexWin : psRegexNix;
          let isAdbRunning = lines.some(function(line) {
            return regex.test(line);
          });
          deferred.resolve(isAdbRunning);
        }
      });

      return deferred.promise;

    }catch(err){
      if(err.name !== "NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND") throw err;
    }

    debug("Error: a task list executable not found on filesystem");
    deferred.resolve(false); // default to restart adb
    return deferred.promise;

  },
```